# A event 'msg' got fired multiple times in socket.io in react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I am creating a chat application using ***nodeJs*** and ***socket**.**io***. Front end is made using ***React***.
I went through many questions on SO, i was not able to get  some of them and some doesn't works.

### React-ChatApp.js

```js
function ChatApp({name,id,handleOnlineUsers}) {
    let displayName = name;
    let meetingId = id;

    let [messages,setMessages] = useState([]);
    let [message,setMessage] = useState(""); 
    let [onlineUsers,setOnlineUsers] = useState(new Map());
    const [socketId,setSocketId] = useState("");

    socket.on("connect",()=>{
        setSocketId(socket.id)
    })
   
    useEffect(()=>{
        socket.emit("join",{displayName,meetingId});
    },[])
   

    socket.on("msg",(msg,socketId,sender)=>{
        console.log("on.msg") // unpredictable
    })


    function handleSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        socket.emit("msg",message,meetingId,displayName)
        console.log(messages)
    }

    return (
        <div className="chat__app">
            <ScrollToBottom className={ROOT_CSS}>
                {/* <Messages messages={messages} currentUserSocketId={socketId}/> */}
            </ScrollToBottom>
            <div className="chat__room">
                <textarea onChange={(e)=>setMessage(e.target.value)} value={message} placeholder="Send message..."></textarea>
                <button id="send__message__button" onClick={(e)=>handleSubmit(e)}>Send</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ChatApp
```

This `socket.on("msg")` got fired multiple times. I can't see any error on server side. Whenever any client fired `msg`  event then i am logging it on the console(server side). I can see the correct message on server side.

#### Suppose

Currently i two clients joins the chat. Client `A` send message `hi`. Then i got `A sends hi` on server  console and on the client console i got `34 on.msg`(see in image below).

[image]

It is looking like, there is a problem on the client side.

### server-index.js

```js
const http = require("http").createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
const chatAPI = require("./server/api/chat");

io.on("connection",(socket)=>{
   chatAPI.connect(socket,io);
})
http.listen(4000,()=>console.log(`I  am running on `))
```

### ./server/api/chat

```js
const chatUsersAPI = require("./chat-room-users");

function connect(socket,io){
    socket.on("join",(user)=>{
        console.log("join",user)
        chatUsersAPI.addNewUser(socket,io,user);
    })

    socket.on("msg",(msg,meetingId,sender)=>{
        console.log("msg->",msg,sender,meetingId)
        socket.to(meetingId).emit("msg",msg,socket.id,sender)
    })
}

const chatAPI = {
    connect:connect
}
module.exports = chatAPI;
```

### ./chat-room-users

```js
let onlineUsers = new Map();

function addNewUser(socket,io,user){
    // join user in room
    try{
        socket.join(user.meetingId,()=>{
            const userInfo = {
                userName:user.displayName,
                roomName:user.meetingId
            }
            onlineUsers.set(socket.id,userInfo);
            const curOnlineUsers = JSON.stringify(Array.from(onlineUsers))
            io.to(user.meetingId).emit("new_user_arrives",curOnlineUsers ) 
        });
    }catch(e){
        console.log("While addUser()->",e)
    }
}

module.exports = {
    addNewUser
}
```

Comment: Can you console.log everytime you 'join' at the backend? Does it have multiple 'Join' events as well?

Comment: It doesn't have multiple join events.

Comment: check how many times  'msg'  event is being sent to a socket frfom Node.js , if it is 1 , then its React issue (mostly re-rendering i suspect)

Comment: This got fired only once on the server side.

Comment: Whenever any user sending a message or joins the chat, then i am logging a message on the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try keeping

```
socket.on("msg",(msg,socketId,sender)=>{
        console.log("on.msg") // unpredictable
    })
```

inside of useEffect (dont listen for 'msg' outside of useEffect)

Comment: Could you tell me what was the problem. As i know `useEffect()` is a life cycle hooks. This can be triggered three time ⌚ in the lifecycle of component. 1.Mounting, 2.Updating, 3. Unmounting. Here i am dealing with updating phase. How messages can be updated multiple times. I tryied a dummy example for this, without use effect, and that works fine.